# Why is this MUI react data grid component rendered 4 times?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I have made a wrapper for MUI Data Grid Component as below:

Selection.tsx:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { DataGrid, faIR, GridSelectionModel } from '@mui/x-data-grid';
import type {} from '@mui/x-data-grid/themeAugmentation';
import { createTheme, makeStyles, ThemeProvider } from '@mui/material/styles';
import { useRef, useState } from "react";
import { TablePagination } from "@mui/material";
import Stack from "@mui/material/Stack";
import DeleteIcon from '@mui/icons-material/Delete';


export default function ControlledSelectionServerPaginationGrid(props: any) {
  const theme = createTheme(
    {
      breakpoints: {
        values: {
          xs: 300,
          sm: 600,
          md: 900,
          lg: 1200,
          xl: 1536
        }
      },
      palette: {
        primary: { main: '#1976d2' },
      },
      components: {
        MuiDataGrid: {
            styleOverrides: {
              root: {
                display: "flex",
                flexDirection: "column-reverse",
                borderRadius: '0',
                paddingRight: '0px',
              },
              menu: {
                  direction: "rtl",
              },
              footerContainer: {
                borderBottom: '1px solid #e0e0e0'
              },
                cell: {
                textAlign: 'right',
                '&:last-child': {
                  textAlign: 'center',
                },
              }


            }
        },
        MuiTablePagination: {
          styleOverrides: {
            root: {
              borderRadius: 'none',
              direction: 'rtl',
            },
            displayedRows: {
              margin: 0,
              direction: 'ltr',
            },
            actions: {
            direction: "ltr"
            }
          }

        },
        MuiToolbar: {
          styleOverrides: {
            root: {
              display: 'flex',
              flexDirection: 'row-reverse',
            }
          }
        },
        MuiTableCell: {
          styleOverrides: {
            root: {
              border: 'none'
            }
          }
        }
      },
    },
    faIR,
  );


  const [page, setPage] = useState<number>(0);
  const { packages, loading } = props.FetchData(page);
  const [selected, setSelected] = useState<any>([]);
  const [rowsPerPage, setRowsPerPage] = useState<number>(15);


  const handleChangePage = (event: React.MouseEvent<HTMLButtonElement> | null, pageNumber: number) => {
    setPage(pageNumber);
  };

  const handleChangeRowsPerPage = (
    event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement | HTMLTextAreaElement>,
  ) => {
    setRowsPerPage(parseInt(event.target.value));
    setPage(0);
  };


  const CustomFooter = () => {
    return (
        <Stack
          direction="row"
          justifyContent="space-between"
          alignItems="center"
          sx={{
            borderBottom: '1px solid #e0e0e0'
          }}
        >
          <Stack
            direction="row"
            justifyContent="space-between"
            alignItems="center"
            sx={{
              marginRight: '20px',
            }}
          >
            {
              selected && selected.length > 0 && (
                  <DeleteIcon sx={{color: "gray", cursor: 'pointer'}} onClick={() => alert('deleted them all')} />
              )
            }
          </Stack>
          <CustomPagination/>
        </Stack>
    )
  }

  const CustomPagination = () => {
    return (
      <TablePagination
        count={packages?.meta?.last_page}
        page={page}
        onPageChange={handleChangePage}
        rowsPerPage={rowsPerPage}
        labelRowsPerPage={false}
        onRowsPerPageChange={handleChangeRowsPerPage}
        rowsPerPageOptions={[15, 30, 45, 60]}
      />
    )
  }

  return (
    <div style={{ height: '790px', width: '100%' }}>
      <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
        {
          loading ? (
              <div>
                loading
              </div>
          ) : (
              <DataGrid
                rows={packages.data}
                getRowId={(row) => row.uuid}
                columns={props.columns}
                pagination
                components={{Footer: CustomFooter}}
                checkboxSelection
                disableSelectionOnClick
                hideFooterSelectedRowCount
                loading={loading}
                onSelectionModelChange={(ids) => {
                  setSelected(ids);
                }}
              />
          )
        }
      </ThemeProvider>

    </div>
  );
}
```

I have the below hook as well which I'm passing to the above component as FetchData:

usePackages.tsx:

```
export default function usePackages(page: number) {
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState<boolean>(false);
  const [packages, setPackages] = useState<any>({
    data: [],
    meta: {},
    links: {}
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    setLoading(true);
    getListOfAllPackages(page)
      .then(data => {
        setPackages({
          ...data.data,
        });
        setLoading(false);
      })
      .catch(error => {
        setLoading(false);
      });
  }, [page]);

  return { packages, loading };
```

Now the way I'm using the above components is just like below:

Packages.tsx:

```
import usePackages from "../../../hooks/Package/usePackages";

     const configValues = (params: any) => {
        return `${params.row.config.hdd}, ${params.row.config.cpu}, ${params.row.config.ram}`
      }
      
      const columns = [
        {
          field: "product_name",
          headerName: "Product Name",
          width: '200',
          flex: 1
        },
        {
          field: "name",
          headerName: "Name",
          width: '400',
          flex: 1
        },
        {
          field: "config",
          headerName: "Config",
          width: '150',
          flex: 1,
          valueGetter: configValues,
        },
        {
          field: "description",
          headerName: "Description",
          width: '350',
          flex: 1
        },
        {
          field: 'actions',
          type: 'Actions',
          width: '100',
          flex: 1,
        },
      ]
    
    
      
    
      return (
        <div style={{ display: 'flex', height: '100%', marginTop: '64px'}}>
          <div style={{ flexGrow: 1 }}>
            <ControlledSelectionServerPaginationGrid columns={columns} FetchData={usePackages}/>
          </div>
        </div>
      )
```

Now my Selection.tsx renders nearly 4 times and making the other components open with delay like modals and the Side Nav, I tried to console log everything and found out it's because of my passed hook props.FetchData that Selection.tsx re-renders itself, hence checking usePackages.tsx and finding out nothing is wrong. I've used such pattern previously and didn't confront such related issues.

Comment: My experience with `useEffect` has a long 'hair pulling' history. Make sure that you add a conditional to it like `if(!packages){ getListOfAllPackages(page) .... `

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure the exact reason for these rerenders though. But I saw some potential things that may affect it.

First, I think it's better to put some variables like `theme` outside of your component body. Because on each rerender, this variable recreates.

Then, make sure to memorize some of the functions that you are using inside your component body like `CustomPagination` and `CustomFooter` with the `useMemo` hook. Because these are recreating with every rerender that happens, too.

After that, based on my experience, it's better to not pass functions through props. Because React can not compare functions for previous props and next props for each rerender. It's better to abstract functions and import them into the component file that you need.
Here, you can import `usePackages` directly from `Selection.tsx` instead of using it from props.
That's the idea behind hooks.